# R squared for a zero-truncated negative binomial model

Tags: r-squared, glmm

Does anyone know how to calculate R squared for a zero-truncated NBM (ZTNB)? I used the methods developed by  Nakagawa and Schielzeth 2013 and Nakagawa *et al*. 2017 to calculate R squared for Poisson model and NBM; haven't found any such method for ZTNB so far.

Comment: What’s wrong with the usual equation, $R^2=1-\dfrac{\sum (y_i - \hat y_i)^2}{\sum (y_i - \bar y)^2}?$

Comment: Because the conventional R squared was developed for linear models and for response variables with a normal distribution, it becomes tricky to apply it to a linear mixed model and where the responses are non-normal. From Nakagawa and Schielzeth 2013: "The third problem of generalizing R2 is particularly profound because the residual variance cannot be easily defined for non-Gaussian responses."

Comment: Nothing in that equation assumes a normal conditional distribution or linear regression. I can apply that to a deep neural network doing binary classification. There might be a better way to assess model performance, but the calculations all make some kind of sense. So…what insights do you want from your modified $R^2?$